need help making prolog program for song
I need to write a prolog program for the song "Im my own grandpa", but its not working. Can anyone help me out. It needs to work in the GNU Prolog console. My code it below
wife(widow, i).
wife(redhair, dad).
daughter(redhair, widow).
daughter(Child, Father) :-
    wife(Mother, Father), 
    daughter(Child, Mother).
father(dad, i).
son_in_law(Child, Spouse) :-
    wife(Daughter, Child), 
    daughter(Daughter, Spouse).
mother(Mother, Child) :-
    wife(Mother, Father), 
    father(Father, Child).
sibling(Child1, Child2) :-
    son_in_law(Child1, Father), 
    father(Father, Child2).
grandparent(Grandparent, Grandchild) :-
    father(Grandparent, Parent), 
    father(Parent, Grandchild).
uncle(Uncle, NieceNephew) :-
    sibling(Uncle, Parent), 
    father(Parent, NieceNephew).
main :-
    write('Is redhair the daughter of i ?: '), 
    daughter(redhair, i), nl, 
    write('Is dad the son in law of i ?: '), 
    son_in_law(dad, i), nl, 
    write('Is baby the brother of dad ?: '), 
    sibling(dad, baby), nl, 
    write('Is baby the uncle of i ?: '), 
    uncle(baby, i), nl, 
    write('Is baby the brother of redhair ?: '), 
    sibling(baby, redhair), nl, 
    write('Is widow the mother of redhair ?: '), 
    mother(widow, redhair), nl, 
    write('Is i the grandfather of i ?: '), 
    grandparent(i, _), nl, halt.

Ive been working on it for a while but cant figure it out. right now it says no after first write  statement of main. If someone can help it will be appreciated

Debug your program - https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger

Hi there. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.
